# How to split a string with regex

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, flash

Would anyone know how I would go about splitting a string like this using Regex?

```
str:String = "word1:word2:6";
```

I need to split it into 3 parts, the separator is :

```
//output
w1 = word1
w2 = word2
num = 6
```

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Why do you feel that you need a regular expression to solve this problem? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: lol. I understand regex is extremely fast and thought that would be a better option than array splitting. A comparison between both options would be interesting as I have to perform this task many times over a 15 minute period.

Comment: For the simple case of splitting based on a single character, using `string.Split` will beat any regex-based solution hands down. It's not even worth the time to benchmark it, there is no question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use RegExp for this.

```
var a:Array = str.split(':');
```

That will create an array where each index is the characters between the common delimeter.

So:

```
a = [word1, word2, 6]
```

You then can parse the array how you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a RegExp to achieve this:

```
str:String = "word1:word2:6";
var arr:Array = str.split(":");
w1 = arr[0];
w2 = arr[1];
num = arr[3];
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies. It looks like you both answered together and unfortunately I can't select both as correct answers (although they are the same).